# qgis2web and keep the data in database

Tags: qgis, qgis2web, qgis-3

I just found the `qgis2web` plugin, what a nice plugin!

Is there any possibility/option to keep the data in a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Sorin RUSU says, the answer is no, not without adding extra components. People's browsers can only communicate with web servers (simplifying wildly), not database servers. The way around this is (in the case of vector layers) to create a WFS server, which can be hosted on the same server as your database if you want, or it can be hosted somewhere else. You configure the WFS server to connect to your database, and to publish the dB layers you need. It does so as a web server, which means your users' browsers *can* connect to it.

Comment: great answer. Could you please point me to resources on how to set up a WFS server?

Comment: I'd search for some beginners' guides to Geoserver. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, not really. 
The plugin exports data to a JSON file when it creates the application. you might publish the data from the database with a GIS Server application, like Geoserver/deegree/Mapserver (to stay in the realm of open source software), and then read the data via WFS in a web application. But this requires some coding.

Postgis doesn't really have a web service that publishes data.

Comment: Using WFS in qgis2web requires no coding. Obviously, setting up a WFS server is a fairly large undertaking, depending on you project, but the qgis2web element works.